How to set and use in code base URL link using Flavors?
I am implementing flavors in my app. I set them like this:
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        production {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField "string", "BASE_URL", "https://example.dev.com;"
        }
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField "string", "BASE_URL", "https://example.prod.com"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
    }

and I want to access BASE_URL in my code, but I don't really know how and I am struggling to find answer.
I tried to use BuildConfig.BASE_URL but I can't use it as IDE saying it's undefined name.
It is a way to access BASE_URL directly in code or should I create some function which will be setting BASE_URL in code depending on actual flavor?

Try thiese packages recommended by flutter docs :
https://github.com/AngeloAvv/flutter_flavorizr
https://github.com/lrferreiro/flutter_flavor
The second one has an example for the base_url

I'm unsure of the way you're injecting the BASE_URL, but perhaps this can read it? It works when passing in with --dart-define, and should also as args/toolArgs (unsure which) in the launch config.
const baseUrl = bool.hasEnvironment("BASE_URL")
    ? String.fromEnvironment("BASE_URL")
    : "https://example.dev.com";

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/String.fromEnvironment.html
